# How to apply a boolean operation in an NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have the following Search NSPredicate

```
NSPredicate *searchPredicateTextComponent = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(entities, $x , ((ANY $x.objects.type LIKE 'text') AND ((ANY $x.objects.desc CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (ANY $x.objects.desc BEGINSWITH[c] %@)))).@count != 0)", [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",subString],subString ];
```

Now I need to block the objects that don't have a boolean combination to be true which is: 
i.e. if P = $x.isAllowed, S = $x.shouldByPass then boolean operation P'S == TRUE must be added to the NSPredicate.

Is this possible or feasible?

Comment: Do you mean by adding `AND ($x.isAllowed AND $x.shouldByPass)` to your predicate?

Comment: Yes. And any sort of boolean evaluation using the collection's entities